# React Typescript - Error TS2339 using React Context

Tags: reactjs

I am getting error TS2339 using React Context when passing `company_token` variable as the result of the first API call (`doGetToken`). The error states `"company_token" does not exist on type 'Company[]'"`

The company objects: `{company_token:"43fwef4"}`

```
import {useCompany} from "../utils/company-context/company-context";
import { Company } from "../types";

const Home = () => {

    const {loadCompany, company} = useCompany();

    const href = window.location.href;

    useEffect(() => {

        const load = async () => {

            await call(
                () => doGetToken('https://quadrifoglio.expressleather.app'),
                (response) => {
                    if (response !== undefined) {
                        if (response) loadCompany(response);
                    }
                }
            )

           await call(
                () => doGetArticles(company.company_token),
                (response) => {
                    if (response.articles) loadArticles(response.articles);
                    if (response.categories) loadCategories(response.categories);
                }
            )
       
        }

        load();
    }, []);


    return (
        <Layout payoffDisplay={true}>

        </Layout>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

I belive that the error is in my context export interface. In which the company_token its not declared. But actually, being a TS beginner i have no clue how to do.

```
import React from 'react';
import CompanyReducer, { defaultState } from './company-reducer';
import { Company } from '../../types';
import actions from "./company-actions";

type CompanyProviderProps = { children: React.ReactNode };

export interface CompanyContextData {
    company: Company[];
    loadCompany: (company: []) => void,

}

const CompanyContextDefaultValue: CompanyContextData = {
    company: [],
    loadCompany: () => null,

};

const CompanyContext = React.createContext<CompanyContextData>(CompanyContextDefaultValue);

function useCompanyContextValue() {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(CompanyReducer, defaultState);

    const { company} = state;

    const loadCompany = React.useCallback((company: []) => dispatch(actions.loadCompany(company)), []);

    return React.useMemo(() => {
        return {
            company, loadCompany,
        };
    }, [
        company, loadCompany,
    ]);
}

function CompanyProvider({ children }: CompanyProviderProps) {
    const value = useCompanyContextValue();
    return <CompanyContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</CompanyContext.Provider>;
}

function useCompany(): CompanyContextData {
    const context = React.useContext(CompanyContext);
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error('useArticles must be used within an ArticleProvider');
    }
    return context;
}

export { useCompany, CompanyProvider };
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `company` is a state that is updated asychronously after the first `call()` invocation: it is not guaranteed to be immediately available after the first promise resolves. Instead, move the logic that consumes `company.company_token` into a separate `useEffect` that has it as a dependency:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const load = async () => {
    await call(
      () => doGetToken('https://quadrifoglio.expressleather.app'),
      (response) => {
        if (response !== undefined) {
          if (response) loadCompany(response);
        }
      }
    )
  }
  load();
}, []);

// Watch changes to `company` and perform second call when `company.company_token` is available
useEffect(() => {
  const getArticles = async () => {
    await call(
      () => doGetArticles(company.company_token),
      (response) => {
        if (response.articles) loadArticles(response.articles);
        if (response.categories) loadCategories(response.categories);
      }
    )
  };

  if (company.company_token) {
    getArticles();
  }
}, [company]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but still the error TS2339: Property 'company_token' does not exist on type 'Company[]'. persists..

Comment: Then you need to share what `company` is. It seems like you're returning an array instead of an object: an important piece of information that you've left out in your original question. What does `company` look like?

Comment: sure, company its an object shaped like {"company_token":"43fwef4"}

Comment: I believe this is the problem ... tho i can not figure out how to modify my context interface / defaultValue

Comment: Then it's your typing that is incorrect: `company: Company[];`